# Migration from Marklogic to MySql

Tags: mysql, marklogic, nosql

I need to make a replication of Marklogic data base into MySql db. Xml files storing by Marklogic I need to save as blob fields in tables of MySql. How can I do it?

Comment: How many files in MarkLogic?  Is this a one-time dump or periodic sync or on-going real-time replication?  Have you already looked at [mlcp](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp) for export from MarkLogic?  How about the [marklogic java-api](http://developer.marklogic.com/adventure/developer/java/start) or [node.js api](http://developer.marklogic.com/adventure/developer/nodejs/start)?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to decide what your MarkLogic xml documents are, and how they are named.   If your database is full of cataloging records for books, for example, maybe you have one xml document per book.

If there's just one series of documents in your MarkLogic system, you'll create one table in MySQL. Each row of the table will contain one xml document. The table's character set should be `utf8mb4` for best results storing xml. It will have, at first anyway, three columns:

- id INT an autoincrementing surrogate primary key.
- name  VARCHAR(250)   the name of each xml document. This name probably comes from an element within each document you extract.
- doc TEXT

You might give the `id` column the `BIGINT` data type if you know you'll have more than 2^31 rows in  the table.

I'm guessing (250) the size of the `name` column. It depends on your data.

The `TEXT` datatype holds up to 64K bytes in each row. If any of your xml documents are bigger than that, you could use the `MEDIUMTEXT` datatype; it holds up to 2^24 bytes in each row.  TEXT and MEDIUMTEXT are CLOBs -- character large objects.

It's generally better to use CLOBs than BLOBs for xml documents, because they handle the utf8 of xml more elegantly.

You then write a program to extract each MarkLogic document in turn, and INSERT it into its own row in the MySQL database.

If your MarkLogic database contains more than one series of documents, you have a decision to make.  For example, you might have books and periodicals. In that case, you have two choices.

1. create a separate table for each document type, for example a `book` and a `periodical` table.
2. add a `doctype` column to your single table and store all the documents in one table. For example, you could give each row's `doctype` column the value `book` or `periodical` depending on its contents.

It's hard to help you choose between these two alternatives without knowing more about your application.

A benefit of MarkLogic is efficient xpath-style searching of large sets of xml documents. If you need to search this MySQL database on anything besides the document name, you'll need to build other purpose-build cross-referencing tables containing

- searchable value.
- id (the id of the document in your first table)

If you have bibliographic records, you might have cross-referencing tables for author, title, isbn, catalog number, etc.

Then you can retrieve the documents matching particular searchable values.